# Union of projection of subsubdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in which each document has an array of subdocuments that have a property (subsubdocument) that may be null.

I want to get all the subsubdocuments then make a new document that consists of a few of its properties that I'm interested in.

For example

```
data

{subs: [{subsub: null}, {subsub: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}}, {subsub: {a: 'c', b: 'd'}}]},
{subs: [{subsub: null}, {subsub: {a: 'e', b: 'f'}}, {subsub: {a: 'g', b: 'h'}}]},

result

[{a; 'a'}, {a: 'c'}, {a: 'e'}, {a: 'g'}]
```

So I want to project the subsubdocuments to a simpler structure, find all the ones that aren't null (and then I'll be wanting to aggregate which would be a simple `GROUP BY` in SQL).

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$subs" },
  { "$match": { "subs.subsub": { "$ne": null }}},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": { "$addToSet": { "a": "$subs.subsub.a" }}
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlaygound**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L_wxkg6pszq)

Or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$subs" },
  { "$match": { "subs.subsub": { "$ne": null }}},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$subs.subsub.a" }},
  { "$project": { "a": "$_id", "_id": false }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VaedECSYaTK)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the trick: I want `aggregate` not `find` and `unwind` pulls out the subdocuments.

Comment: I think this is what you wanted.